# Replace content inside two specific lines

Tags: sed, replace, text

How to replace, from command-line, the content between `<!-- Analytics code start -->` and `<!-- Analytics code end -->` of `index.html`:

```
<html>
...

<!-- Analytics code start -->
...
<!-- Analytics code end -->
</body>
</html>
```

by the content of a file, say `myanalytics.txt` ?

*Note: I want to do it by command-line because I need to do it for many files.*

Comment: you wan't to change the content between these two lines ??

Comment: Sorry @Sidahmed what did you mean?

Comment: lets say `<!-- Analytics code start -->` is at the line **4**, and `<!-- Analytics code end -->` is the line **10**. Do you wanna change the lines 4 and 10, or  the lines between 4 and 10 ??

Comment: @Sidahmed The lines between 4 and 10.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `awk` could be:

```
awk '/Analytics code start/ { t=1; print; system("cat myanalytics.txt") } 
     /Analytics code end/   { t=0 } 
     t==0 { print } ' index.html
```

(I indented the code to increase readability, but it can easily be a oneline)

**Briefly explanation:**

- When `t==0` always print the current line
- If the current line matches `"Analytics code start"` set `t==1` and then print the current line and the desired file with `system("cat myanalytics.txt")`
- Now `t` is equal to `1` so the current line is never printed, but when the current line matches `"Analytics code end"`, `t` is set to `0` again, so print the current line from now on.

**Note:**

This will not edit your file `index.html`.
To modify `index.html` you can:

- redirect the output from `awk` to a temporary file, and then use a command like`mv` or `cp`
- use `sponge` from `moreutils` package, as follow:

  ```
  awk '[.. commands like above ..]' index.html | sponge index.html
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Given your situation, here's how you could do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

SOURCE=index.html
if ! test -f "$SOURCE"; then
    echo source is missing >&2
    exit 1
fi

headLimit=`grep -n '<!-- Analytics code start -->' "$SOURCE" | cut -d: -f1`
tailLimit=`grep -n '<!-- Analytics code end -->' "$SOURCE" | cut -d: -f1`
linennr=`awk '{}END{print NR + 1}' $SOURCE`

if ! test "$headLimit" -gt 0 -a "$tailLimit" -gt 0 >/dev/null; then
    echo something is wrong >&2
    exit 2
fi
(
    head -n$headLimit "$SOURCE"
    echo "the stuff I want to inject in place of my analytics code"
    tail -n`expr $linennr - $tailLimit` "$SOURCE"
) >"$SOURCE.new"

if test -s "$SOURCE.new"; then
    mv "$SOURCE" "$SOURCE.old"
    mv "$SOURCE.new" "$SOURCE"
fi

exit 0
```

Note that any `ed` based solution would allow to actually replace in-file, instead of generate a replacement one, ... Which would arguably be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! It seems complex, I thought it could be done in one line, don't you think it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

i think this maybe work

```
sed -rn '/<!-- Analytics code start -->/{ 
           p; :X n; /<!-- Analytics code end -->/{p;b}; bX
        }; p'
```